# Is boot-repair becoming our jQuery?

Tags: discussion, answers

> For those that do not know the jQuery meme, [please read it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/213575) or you will not be able to know what I'm going to talk about.

Well, as all of you know, boot-repair do wonders in modern days helping users fixing their boot, but I've seen that several people for several questions just say "try boot-repair" and repeat and repeat and repeat the very similar answers. Please, don't take me bad, I think boot-repair is awesome, but sometimes I feel that we are just throwing an *ave maria* answer hoping boot-repair will solves all issues with boot/dual-boot/UEFI. So, what folks feels about this?

Comment: Did you try a hard reset? ;)

Comment: Just because someone uses a shoe to hammer a nail once doesn't mean we need a meta post.. Not like anyone even reads meta anyway. If it's a one sentence "try boot repair" flag it to be converted to a comment. If someone is copying an answer, comment about it and flag the answer. Also, jQuery is awesome. More jQueryness can only make boot-repair more awesomer!

Comment: I like the boot-repair ones. Especially when the user says he already tried boot-repair and the answer to his problem is boot-repair just with a different option/setup.

Comment: @Seth say that in the JS room.... (don't tell them I told you ;))

Comment: @falconer I'm taking more about answers that only says "try boot repair <insert boot-repair installation method here"

Comment: I'm really starting to dislike Boot Repair. I think it's overused even when the problem is evident and can be fixed without Boot Repair.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure a common answer makes something a meme. If it's an answer that works to fix the questions being asked, surely that's what we want.

Some issues just have a lot of things you can try before you can definitively say what the problem is. Running Boot Repair can magically fix several different things with a few clicks. It's a bezoar.

I won't worry about it until it starts being posted for issues where it just *can't* be the solution. If you're seeing that, just flag it up as not-an answer and leave a comment so the the poster knows and so the OP can see to not bother with something (rewriting your boot configuration is not risk-free).